Is the で in the -て form of adjectives and noun always the -て form of だ?
The grammar books that I have consulted introduce the -て form of verbs along with the -て form of adjectives and nouns (this is the terminology used in my books; I would say they mean in the sense of the EDIT in this answer by the user naruto, i.e. the -て form of the copula). More specifically, in the case of -な adjectives and nouns, we form it by adding the -て form of the copula だ, that is で. So, first of all I wanted to make sure that this で is really always the て of the copula. It appears to be reasonable in the case of -な adjectives is used with a predicative function

その公園は静かできれいです。

since we are connecting the sentences 「その公園は静かです。」 and 「その公園はきれいです。」 but what about the attributive function? Is it still a copula?

静かできれいな公園

Also, in the same section of one of my books, I learned that the -て form can express a cause. Then in the next section the structure Noun+で was introduced to express a cause. The order of this all really confused me, since this で seems to be the a particle. This is the example provided in that section

私は昨日風邪で休みました。
(Yesterday, because of a cold, I rested/got some rest)

Or also (I got this examples from my book)

レポートでうちにいました。
(Because of the report, I stayed home)

Since this is just a noun I would guess that this is the particle, isn't it? But then, can we also have a Noun+で+sentence where the で is not a particle? For example, in the sentence:

山川さんは日本人で日本語で話します。

I would say that we have instead a -て form of the copula (of course I mean the first で), can you confirm?
Related question (and links therein).

Your view seems entirely correct to me. There are indeed two “〜で” in Japanese. One is the conjunctive form of “〜だ” as such, it comes behind an entire sentence and can carry a subject, adverbs, and so forth. The other is simply a case marking particle like say “〜から” or “〜が” and can come behind a single noun only, never an adjective. I shall call the other the “locative marker” for brevity, but it has many more uses, such as denoting the instrument, cause, and material something is made off. I think it's best to indeed see these are two separate things that just happen to have the same form similar to how many different grammatical things take the form “〜か”, “〜に” or “〜と” or “〜が” in many cases even attaching to different parts of speech. The issue is a bit muddied by that many adjectives are also nouns on top of that. On top of that, the conjunctive form can also be replaced with “〜であって” in theory for a longer form, but this may not always sound natural, and in various fixed expressions it cannot.
For instance in say “レストランで食べている” it is the locative marker. It cannot have it's own subject or adverbs, and it cannot be replaced with “〜であって” for the same meaning. In “いい子でおとなしくする” it's the conjunctive form. It has it's own implied subject, we can use “本当にいい子で” as an adverb which modifies “いい子で” not “おとなしくする” and we can replace it with “いい子であって” in theory to retain the same meaning.

その公園は静かできれいです。

This is indeed the conjunctive form of “〜で”.

静かできれいな公園

This is indeed also the conjunctive form yes.

Also, in the same section of one of my books, I learned that the -て form can express a cause.

The locative use can also express a cause, for instance “どんな理由で食べない？”. I do not believe this to be the conjunctive form because I don't what kind of subject “どんな理由で” could conceivably have which I feel is the important part. In the conjunctive form, it must have at least an implied subject.  In your first example they share the same subject of course.

山川さん日本人で日本語で話します。

Here we have both, again assuming that there is a “は” missing here. “Mr. Yamakawa is Japanese, and thus speaks in Japanese.”. The second one is the locative function. The first one has an explicit subject here, shared with “話します”, the second one cannot conceivably have one. We can see a new usage of the locative here, denoting the language one speaks in which isn't exactly the location the speaking takes place. It also for instance is often used with prices as “１０万円で売る” as in “I sell it for 100 000 yen”. It has many, many uses, as the conjunctive form does, what sets it apart from the conjunctive form is purely the grammatical properties. If we were to include an adverb here and say “本当に１０万円で売る” the adverb will always modify “売る”.
Though the main takeaway is that nouns can take both, and adjectives can only take the conjunctive variant. There are some small worms such as say “本気で”. This is simply the adverbial form of “本気” which isn't really much used as a noun. One could argue that it's the conjunctive form I guess but I think one should just memorize it as the adverbial form because most adjectives don't do this. For whatever reason　the more common “本気に” or “本気と” aren't really used to form the adverbial form and we say “君が本気で好きだ。” to mean “I sincerely love you.”, not “本気に” one could argue that it has an implicit subject here which is also the speaker and that it's thus “I'm serious, and I love you.” but I think that's sort of forcing a square into a circle and it's better to accept that the adverbial form of “本気” is just “本気で”. Of course it can also be conjunctive and be used as “本気で賢い生徒” to mean “a serious and intelligent student” which thus can also mean “A sincerely intelligent student”.

Hello, Zorf. Thank you for your answer. Yes, I meant 休みました and forgot the topic marker below; I edited the post. I have a few things to point out.
1.First, whenever you say "conjunctive form" (which of course connects adjectives and verbs and I know how it works), I suppose you are implying that it is indeed the -て form of the copula. Correct? I only need a yes, if it's the case.

There was probably a misunderstanding about かぜ, which would be 風邪 (cold). That sentence is saying "Yesterday I stayed home because of a cold",  you may want to edit that part where you say it's a location.


Oh yeah, that かぜ, and yes that's what I mean with conjunctive yes.

Hello. The reason why I haven't accepted the answer yet is that I'm still thinking about it. You talk about the で particle as a location/instrument marker, but I realized that I probably was not clear enough. Yes, I know those two usages of the particle. The one I was talking about was another usage to express a cause, comparing it to the ~て form. An example of that is the sentence with かぜ but I  edited my question to add another example to make it more clear. There are many others here

@Mr.Feynman It has many different usages, it can also denoted the material is made of as in “鋼でできている” to mean “made of steel”. I just used “locative/instrumental” to be brief. The issue is not semantics but grammar. One, as the conjunctive form of “〜だ” can have a subject and indeed an entire clause in front of it, the other simply comes behind a single noun, never an adjective, and that's it. I'll edit my answer to be more clear.
